# Is it possible to initialize a Ruby hash with a do block?

Tags: ruby

I love the feel of the Ruby `do ... end` block, and I would love to be able to use it to initialize a hash. I'm aware of the curly brace construction, e.g.

```
h = {
  :a => 10,
  :b => 20
}
```

But I was wondering if there's a way to do the same sort of thing with a do block, e.g.

```
h_keys = keys do
  :a => 10,
  :b => 20
end
```

**Edit**

Let me be clearer: I do understand that a hash literal is not a block, and I have a pretty good grasp of the internals of a block. What I'm wondering is more along the lines of this:

Is it possible, perhaps via (but not constrained to) some clever metaprogramming method, to write a function such that a block passed into it is interpreted as a hash?

Comment: if you google 'ruby hash', you'll find the documentation for it in the top results, and everything you need to know about them (including its constructor, which indeed allows to use a block)

Comment: It is not clear to me... can you a bit more specific? Did you see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-c-new ?

Comment: sawa is correct that the answer is "no", but I wanted to add that it would probably be very beneficial if you get a better understanding of what's going on inside blocks. There are some great blog posts out there (also some explaining the difference between blocks, procs, and lambdas). Once you understand blocks, you'll know what they can and can't do, and using them effectively in your code can be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit similar to your desired sample code, though the `do`...`end` is gone:

```
 def keys(x); x; end
 h = keys a: 1, b: 2
```

Unfortunately `keys do a: 1, b: 2 end` doesn't match Ruby's grammar. Naturally, you *could* still write a preprocessor which would run over a source file, rewrite your added syntax to standard Ruby syntax, then feed it to the interpreter. That would be more than a little crazy, but if you want to do it, more power to you...

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the effort